# iOS Simulator showing blank white screen - Capacitor - Vue.js

Tags: xcode, vue.js, capacitor

Thanks for taking the time to check out my post. A little stuck here with my mobile app project using Capacitor and Vue.js

Long story short, I've got a proper Vue.js set up correctly because I tested with Node server and it functions exactly how we set it up. But when we use Capacitor plugin to boot our Vue.js product with Xcode the simulator shows blank. It does show the Capacitor splash screen and logs mention "Loading app at capacitor://localhost..." and "Web View Loaded" but nothing. I know I installed Capacitor right because I've retried multiple times and it's not rocket science either. I must be missing a step. I have included a screenshot below.

[image: Terminal + Simulator]

Comment: there is an error in those logs, something related to your Xcode installation, failing when pod install is run

Comment: @jcesarmobile I have no errors now. I did a fresh set up and it was an error with Developer Tools. I add to set it in my Xcode preferences. Not sure why it's not working now. No errors whatsoever.

Comment: Try inspecting the app in desktop safari with the remote web inspector, refresh the app (with the reload button on the inspector) since the errors will appear before you open and won’t be displayed otherwise.

Comment: I'm not too sure how to open capacitor with my browser. How I go about that? I don't have any vulnerabilities nor any errors. I've just simply added a Capacitor to an existing Vue.js project. It works with node just fine.

Comment: No, you run the app in the device or simulator, but debug it in desktop safari with the remote web inspector https://appletoolbox.com/use-web-inspector-debug-mobile-safari/

Comment: @jcesarmobile I don't really see much on this debugger. This is such an odd issue

Comment: Did you hit the reload/refresh button? Issues that cause white screen are generated before you can open the debugger and unlike android debugger, they won’t appear. If you hit the reload button those errors should appear.

Comment: @jcesarmobile Did a little further testing just now. We printed "hello" from our index.html file and it does show up on the debugger log when we boot the app and we also sneaked a quick label on the top left corner that says "hi" so we're seeing it read the index.html file but not getting any info from our main.js file. We tried to get console outputs and nothing. At first the safari debugger gave us a google fonts error but we fixed that and still nothing showing up. What you think is happening now? Thanks for helping us get this far though. This is definitely progress.

Comment: at this point, only a sample app can help so somebody can look into it

Answer (score 4):

I had this issue and maybe it's the same for you. The default assets direct for capacitor is the `www` folder. Vue js builds to the `dist` folder. For me, and I "think" for you is you're using a app created with Vue CLI yet you inited your project without specifying the `dist` directory as your assets directory. Add this to your `capacitor.config.json`

```
  "webDir": "dist",
```

Then re-copy the assets

```
npx cap copy
```

Next time init a vue js project create with vue cli use `npx cap init --web-dir dist` to point to the dist folder. If this doesn't work let me know so I can edit the answer rather than downvote.

Comment: This is what I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with the capacitor with react js and solved it with a redirect to `/home` where it was `./` for example

Answer (score 0):

It may helps you

**Solution**

In your projects root folder you have capacitor.config.json file. In this file, we have an object, we need to change “webDir” default value is “src”

{
…
“webDir”: “src”
…
}

“webDir” value will be “www”.

Ref: https://medium.com/@ahmetsezen/ionic-capacitor-app-blank-white-screen-problem-98c0e47ff2d4

Answer (score 0):

I am using Nuxt3 with Capacitor.js.

In my case, the real folder structure in which the project assets was built looked like this `/_nuxt/_nuxt/...`, but the default configs (from the documentation) are: `baseURL: "/"` and `buildAssetsDir: "/_nuxt/"`.

So I defined the `baseURL` parameter in `nuxt.config.ts`

```
export default defineNuxtConfig({
    ssr : false,
    app: {
        baseURL: '/_nuxt/'
    }
})
```

And just in case, don't forget to change the `webDir` in `capacitor.config.json` with

```
"webDir": ".output/public",
```