# Blank page on the emulator - Ionic Vue

Tags: xcode, ionic-framework, capacitor, ionic-vue

I have an ionic vue project that shows a blank screen when I open it on an emulator. Thinking I missed something on my end I then created a new project using the Photo Gallery starter. It too is showing a blank page on the emulator. Any suggestions?

My project’s Ionic Info

```
Ionic:

   Ionic CLI       : 6.13.1 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@ionic/cli)
   Ionic Framework : @ionic/vue 5.8.4

Utility:

   cordova-res (update available: 0.15.3) : 0.15.1
   native-run                             : 1.5.0

System:

   NodeJS : v12.18.0 (/usr/local/bin/node)
   npm    : 7.23.0
   OS     : macOS Big Sur
```

Package list

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@capacitor/camera": "^1.1.0",
    "@capacitor/core": "3.2.3",
    "@capacitor/filesystem": "^1.0.3",
    "@capacitor/ios": "^3.2.3",
    "@capacitor/network": "^1.0.3",
    "@ionic/pwa-elements": "^3.0.2",
    "@ionic/vue": "^5.4.0",
    "@ionic/vue-router": "^5.4.0",
    "@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat": "^2.0.2",
    "autoprefixer": "^9",
    "axios": "^0.23.0",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "postcss": "^7",
    "swiper": "^6.8.4",
    "tailwindcss": "npm:@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat@^2.0.2",
    "vue": "^3.2.1",
    "vue-router": "^4.0.0-0",
    "vuex": "^4.0.0-rc.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@capacitor/cli": "3.2.3",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.0.0-0",
    "@vue/test-utils": "^2.0.0-0",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^7.0.0-0",
    "vue-cli-plugin-tailwind": "~2.0.6",
    "vue-jest": "^5.0.0-0"
  }
```

[image]

Comment: Does this help? https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor/issues/2263 Or maybe this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59294465/ios-simulator-showing-blank-white-screen-capacitor-vue-js

Comment: @1x2x3x4x that's exactly what I needed. thank you.

Comment: Sometimes you only need to rebuild with XCode again...